# Convert numpy array type and values from Float64 to Float32

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, pickle

I am trying to convert threshold array(pickle file of isolation forest from scikit learn) of type from Float64 to Float32

```
for i in range(len(tree.tree_.threshold)):
    tree.tree_.threshold[i] = tree.tree_.threshold[i].astype(np.float32)
```

​
Then Printing it

```
for value in tree.tree_.threshold[:5]:
    print(type(value))
    print(value)
```

the output i am getting is :

```
<class 'numpy.float64'>
526226.0
<class 'numpy.float64'>
91.9514312744
<class 'numpy.float64'>
3.60330319405
<class 'numpy.float64'>
-2.0
<class 'numpy.float64'>
-2.0
```

I am not getting a proper conversion to Float32. I want to convert values and their type to Float32, Did anybody have any workaround this ?

Comment: no, there is no missing values, and max value is 526225.98822

Comment: can you give us print tree.tree_.threshold.flags

Comment: C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Actually i tried hard but not able to do as the
>   'sklearn.tree._tree.Tree' objects is not writable.
>
> It is causing a precision issue while generating a PMML file, so i
>   raised a bug over there and they gave an updated solution for it by
>   not converting it in to the Float64 internally.

For more info, you can follow this link:
[Precision Issue](https://github.com/jpmml/jpmml-converter/issues/6)

Answer (score 54):

The problem is that you do not do any type conversion of the numpy array. You calculate a float32 variable and put it as an entry into a float64 numpy array. numpy then converts it properly back to float64

Try someting like this:

```
a = np.zeros(4,dtype="float64") 
print a.dtype
print type(a[0])
a = np.float32(a)
print a.dtype
print type(a[0])
```

The output (tested with python 2.7)

```
float64
<type 'numpy.float64'>
float32
<type 'numpy.float32'>
```

a is in your case the array tree.tree_.threshold

Comment: can you explain about np.zeroes parameters, specially "4"

Comment: it was the fasted way of created a numpy array that is filled with something... here zeros. The 4 is just the number of zeros. I choose 4 because I like the number...

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-125-d20ee23285ad> in <module>()
----> 1 tree.tree_.threshold = np.zeros(4,dtype="float64")
      2 print (tree.tree_.threshold.dtype)
      3 tree.tree_.threshold= float32(tree.tree_.threshold)
      4 print (a.dtype)

AttributeError: attribute 'threshold' of 'sklearn.tree._tree.Tree' objects is not writable

Comment: getting same error:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-139-0ba8c9d97878> in <module>()
----> 1 tree.tree_.threshold = np.zeros(4,dtype="float64")
      2 print (tree.tree_.threshold.dtype)
      3 print (tree.tree_.threshold[0].dtype)
      4 tree.tree_.threshold= float32(a)
      5 print (tree.tree_.threshold.dtype)

AttributeError: attribute 'threshold' of 'sklearn.tree._tree.Tree' objects is not writable

Comment: well, if its not a writable object, you cannnot overwrite it. Therefore the solution wont work. It only works if you use a new numpy array which you probably don't want.

Comment: yes, i want to modify the existed one.Is there any way to modify it ?

Comment: you can try tree.tree_.threshold.dtype="float32"

Comment: no, it is not allowing me to do it causing an error "ValueError: new type not compatible with array."

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
tree.tree_.threshold[i]=tree.tree_.threshold[i].astype('float32',casting='same_kind’)
```