# Opencv error -Unsupported depth of input image:

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to convert a normalised RGB image to HSV or LAB colour space. 
Here is the normalisation function:[image]

here is the basic code

```
print ('original image shape: ', image.shape)
print ('normlaised image shape: ', needed_multi_channel_img.shape)
# Converting to LAB color space


lab_image = cv.cvtColor(needed_multi_channel_img, cv.COLOR_RGB2HSV)

cv.imshow('Lab_space.jpg',lab_image.astype('float32'))
cv.waitKey(0)
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is the output trace:

```
    /home/centura/gitlab/Acne_model/Acne Model/rosaceaexperiment1.py:82: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in true_divide
  norm.append(image[i,j,a]/rooted_matrix[i,j])
/home/centura/gitlab/Acne_model/Acne Model/rosaceaexperiment1.py:82: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide
  norm.append(image[i,j,a]/rooted_matrix[i,j])
original image shape:  (375, 600, 3)
normlaised image shape:  (375, 600, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/centura/gitlab/Acne_model/Acne Model/rosaceaexperiment1.py", line 121, in <module>
    lab_image = cv.cvtColor(needed_multi_channel_img, cv.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3) /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.hpp:257: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'cv::CvtHelper<VScn, VDcn, VDepth, sizePolicy>::CvtHelper(cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray, int) [with VScn = cv::Set<3, 4>; VDcn = cv::Set<3>; VDepth = cv::Set<0, 5>; cv::SizePolicy sizePolicy = (cv::SizePolicy)2u; cv::InputArray = const cv::_InputArray&; cv::OutputArray = const cv::_OutputArray&]'
> Unsupported depth of input image:
>     'VDepth::contains(depth)'
> where
>     'depth' is 6 (CV_64F)
```

For zero division error, I have replaced it with 0 and nan is also replaced with 0.

I also searched through StackOverflow but could not find any information to debug it.
I do not understand the meaning of this error and how to rectify it.

Comment: your image type is `CV_64F` (`float64`) which is not supported by `cvtColor` function. Convert the image to an appropriate type, e.g. `float32`

Comment: is there a simple way to convert it to float32.

Comment: like any other numpy array, with `astype`

Comment: i tried it 
`normal_image[:,:,0] = normal_image[:,:,0].astype(np.float32)`
`normal_image[:,:,1] = normal_image[:,:,1].astype(np.float32)`
`normal_image[:,:,2] = normal_image[:,:,2].astype(np.float32)`
still the error persists.

Comment: Is there any other method. I am still getting error @Miki

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python: OpenCV depth of image unsupported (CV\_64F)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55128386/python-opencv-depth-of-image-unsupported-cv-64f)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45956247/7683041, try:

```
img_float32 = np.float32(needed_multi_channel_img)
lab_image = cv.cvtColor(img_float32, cv.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
```

Answer (score 0):

I actually had a similar issue, the problem was that the input was in floats but it was expecting integers. when i converted to integers (.astype('int')) this error disappeared. maybe I'll help you too.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).